# Javascript async function with fetch api not pushing to variable

Tags: javascript, async-await

Hello just learning async functions. I'm attempting to push the results of a fetch call to an array from within an async function

Console result is 0 (there are 10 users). Love to know what I'm doing wrong, thanks

```js
        let users = [];
    async function fetchUsers() {
      const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      users.push(data);
    }
    fetchUsers();
    console.log(`There are ${users.length} users`)
```

Comment: You're also not invoking `fetchUsers` anywhere.

Comment: Oops thanks will edit snippet

Comment: @James, now, you do not `await fetchUsers();`, therefore, the length is 0 ;)

Comment: @sjahan — The call to `fetchUsers` is not inside an async function so it can't be awaited.

Comment: I agree, but that just explains why the length is still 0. OP just need to run it in an `async` func, or use `.then()`.